# Will getting my new iPad engraved delay its delivery?

Tags: ipad

I've looked on Apple's site and I can't seem to find any information on whether having an iPad engraved will add a substantial amount of time to the shipping. Does anyone have any first hand experience?

Will there be a delay? If so, for how long?

I'm based in London, I'm not sure if that will make any difference.

Also: I'm not bothered by the idea that I will be "devaluing" my iPad by getting it engraved. I tend to use electronic devices until the end of their life.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, yes, there will be a delay.

The thing is that when you order engraving (at least it was like this when I ordered), Apple does it in a factory somewhere in China, and ships it from there, which takes forever (it took a little more than a week if I remember correctly to ship it to New York).

If you don't order the engraving, Apple can send an iPad that they have in stock somewhere much closer to where you are, which will be faster.

Comment: Almost all Apple products are shipped direct for the factory in China.